# finding the gain of a two stage voltage amplifier

Tags: amplifier, gain, theory

i currently do not know how to approach this question, in terms of simplifying the circuit and which formulas to use in order to find the gain

[image: link to the exact question]
[image: as well as the amplifier diagram]

Comment: What have you done so far? What are the things you do know about the problem?

Comment: How would you start for finding the solution? What would be the 1st quantity you would like to calculate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### General approach

First, you must calculate the bias conditions, as any of these values will serve to find transistor parameters applicable to small signal model.
Then, you must determine the small-signal equivalent circuit, based on the [hybrid model of transistor](http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Theory/tr_model.htm).
From the equivalent model, it comes down to solve the network to find the relationship between the output variable and input, i.e. the gain. With the same model, you can find the input and output impedances.

### Recommendations

If this is the first time you solve a circuit of this type, it may be easier to start with a single transistor. The resolution principle is the same.
Draw many equivalent circuits as needed. Draw these circuits carefully.
It is very important to correctly appliques concept [impedance reflection](https://coefs.uncc.edu/dlsharer/files/2012/04/C3.pdf), especially in the example circuit having emitter resistors without uncoupling.

Answer (score 1):

[image: page1]

[image: page2]

Here is the solution. These are pretty basic stuff. You should have learned it by now.

Comment: I think, you should mention that this is a rather rough solution only. This is because you did not take into account the base current which - in this case - is a rather good portion of the current through (R1+R2).